# Изменить/убрать уведомление об улучшении сообщения для мета вопросов/ответов при голосе "против"

Tags: обсуждение, предложение

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Предлагаю убрать это уведомление, т.к. (насколько я знаю) на мете голоса "за" и "против" буквально означают, что я "за" идею/предложение/и т.д. или "против". Потому уведомление при голосе "против" что "сообщение можно улучшить" как по мне абсолютно бессмысленно

Но я предполагаю что это скорее всего стандартно для всех платформ, потому не станут это убирать. Но если это нельзя убрать, то хотя бы надо изменить содержимое на что-то более подходящее по смыслу.

Например, что-то типа:

> Пожалуйста оставьте комментарий почему вы против предложенной идеи

Понятно, что тут не только идеи обсуждаются, потому это не совсем корректно, но в целом надеюсь суть донёс. Просто если буду адекватные идеи для изменения содержимого, то это будет гораздо легче через переводы исправить, если, конечно, ключи переводов разные

[Этот же вопрос на английской мете](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422697/change-remove-post-improvement-notification-when-downvote-meta-questions-answers)

Comment: Основная мета - это всё же [meta.se], а не [meta.so].

Comment: @αλεχολυτ Исправил :)

Answer (score 2):

Даже на мете голоса "вверх" и "вниз" не всегда означают "за"/"против" [конкретного вопроса (источник из справки)](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/whats-meta):

> В отличие от «обычных сайтов» сети Stack Exchange, Мета позволяет сообществу обсуждать, аргументировано спорить, предлагать изменения жизни самого сообщества и работы программного обеспечения. Для сообщений, обозначенных как предложение, голосование обозначает согласие (одобрение) или несогласие с предлагаемым изменением, а не качество или пользу самого сообщения.

Каждый вопрос на Мете должен иметь как минимум одну из четырех меток: [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5), [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0).

- Часто голоса "вверх"/"вниз" действительно означают "за"/"против" в вопросах [предложение](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b6%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5). [Но и это не всегда так](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/146057/383809): Даже для вопросов-предложений **согласие-несогласие лишь один из факторов** (тут есть несколькое противоречие с "буквой" прописанной в справке, но по сути — я не вижу проблемы).
- Иногда (по факту) это также происходит с вопросами в теге [дефект](/questions/tagged/%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%84%d0%b5%d0%ba%d1%82), но гораздо реже, и чаще в значении "баг" это или "фича".
- Для вопросов в [обсуждение](/questions/tagged/%d0%be%d0%b1%d1%81%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b4%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) и [поддержка](/questions/tagged/%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b4%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b6%d0%ba%d0%b0) — "за"/"против" попросту неприменимо.

Таким образом, **желаемое поведение невозможно исполнить, если не обеспечить возможность различных подсказок на кнопках "вверх"/"вниз" для различных тегов.** А таковое очень навряд ли возможно и требует изменение механики глубоко-глубоко в механизмах движка.

1. Такое предложение [уже было предложено на основной Мете](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75049/383809) и **было отклонено** в 2011. А также несколько [дубликатов](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/98748/383809).
2. [Запрос на пересмотр с похожей формулировкой был предложен на основной мете в 2020](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/364061/383809) и, не набрав значительной поддержки и просмотров в целом, был проигнорирован.

Дополнительные англоязычные материалы на тему:

- [Voting on Meta is not just for (dis)agreement. Update the help center to reflect this](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/187018/383809)
- [Do downvotes on Meta truly mean something different?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/126590/383809)
- [Why doesn't tooltip reflect what people say?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/201678/383809)

Comment: Спасибо большое за подробный ответ! Прочитав ваш ответ, я ещё больше убедился в бессмысленности текста, в уведомление :) Если невозможно объективно придумать более универсальный текст для уведомления, то его лучше убрать впринципе для меты

Comment: @EzioMercer я, в целом, с вами согласен, что хорошо бы что-то с этим сделать. Однако для данного конкретно предложения, к сожалению, только один путь — это обеспечивать некую механику (будь то ваше оригинальное предложение или любая другая модификация) для всех мета сайтов — а это на основную мету, где вопрос перетирался много раз. Реалии, будь они не ладны.

Comment: Постараюсь поднять вопрос на основной мете, вдруг мне повезёт :)